How long should it take to install 24.04 from a USB install disk? Minimal install, no encryption, no 3rd party download?
Tried installing 24.04 onto a 1 Tb sandisk 3.2 USB, from a 16gb install USB, also 3.2 sandisk.
Using minimal installation, no encryption, no 3rd party downloads.
It's already taken more than 6 hrs. The  terminal screen shows each packet as it downloads, but some of them take over an hour.
It's still working but not finished.
How long should it take?

You mention a release; but not which 24.04 product & installer you're using (selected when you download; ie. server, desktop etc).  Installs vary on time based on speed of machine, disk, and if downloads are required what those will be (package updates etc; also varying on what ISO you used to install; an older 24.04 ISO, newer 24.04.1, or newer daily etc).  If you want the fastest install, install offline or without update of packages (update them packages yourself later)..  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS has different installers though; and you've not specified which you used.

Are you sure you are using USB3 ports and not USB2 ports?  I'd guess an hour max, but I've been using SSDs for awhile, so 10-20 minutes.
